# jquerymobile-TypeError: Object doesn't support this action on windows phone

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, phonegap, windows-phone, cordova

Obtaining

> TypeError: Object doesn't support this action

in windows phone 8.1, IE v11. The application is plotting route and drawing circles in Android & iOS devices.

Is there any compatibility issue for `ArcGIS for Javascript` with windows phone? I am using dojo script to load the map..

I have a requirement for finding route between to points using `RouteTask` on my custom map layer. A `TypeError` is obtained on calling

```
var routeTask = new RouteTask(myRouteServerURL);
```

The same errors are obtained on initializing `Circle` and `graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(features)` statements...
This is the require module used in my application

```
require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",
    "esri/graphic",
    "esri/SpatialReference",
    "esri/geometry/Point",
    "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils",
    "esri/InfoTemplate",
    "esri/lang",
    "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
    "esri/tasks/FeatureSet",
    "esri/graphicsUtils",
    "esri/tasks/RouteTask",
    "esri/tasks/RouteParameters",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/Color",
    "esri/geometry/Circle", 
    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
    "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "dojo/_base/connect",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/domReady!"
    ],
    function(Map, PictureMarkerSymbol, Graphic, SpatialReference, Point, webMercatorUtils, 
      InfoTemplate, lang, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, FeatureSet, graphicsUtils, RouteTask, 
      RouteParameters, SimpleLineSymbol, Color, Circle, SimpleFillSymbol, GraphicsLayer, connect, on) {
            .......
            routeTask = new RouteTask(myRouteServerURL);
            .......
            var circle = new Circle({
              center: point,
              radius: 50
            });
            .......
});
```

I used the code the same code provided in [Find a Route](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/routetask_find_route.html).